# How to serialize Scala Map<String, MyObj> in Play Framework

Tags: json, playframework

So I basically have code like:

```
case class MyObj( value:String, unit: String)
case class ObjSeries( id: String, myObjs: Map[String, MyObj] )
```

However, creating writers like:

```
implicit val myObjWrites = Json.writes[MyObj]

implicit val objSeriesWrites: Writes[ObjSeries] = (
   (JsPath \ "id").write[String] and 
   (JsPath \ "myObjs").write[Map[String, MyObj]]
)(unlift(ObjSeries.unapply))
```

Fails with " overloaded method value apply with alternatives - cannot be applied to...".

What am I missing?

---

The above is of course a simple example; the actual data structures I'm working on are a bit more complex. The actual example is a class:

```
case class ObservationSeries(
  sourceId: Option[String],
  geometry: Option[Point],
  levels: Option[Seq[Level]],
  referenceTime: Option[String],
  observations: Option[Map[String, Observation]]
)
```

And the error message goes:

```
overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
[error]   [B](f: B => (Option[String], Option[no.met.geometry.Point], Option[Seq[no.met.geometry.Level]], Option[String], Option[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,models.Observation]]))(implicit fu: play.api.libs.functional.ContravariantFunctor[play.api.libs.json.OWrites])play.api.libs.json.OWrites[B] <and>
[error]   [B](f: (Option[String], Option[no.met.geometry.Point], Option[Seq[no.met.geometry.Level]], Option[String], Option[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,models.Observation]]) => B)(implicit fu: play.api.libs.functional.Functor[play.api.libs.json.OWrites])play.api.libs.json.OWrites[B]
[error]  cannot be applied to (models.ObservationSeries => (Option[String], Option[no.met.geometry.Point], Option[Seq[no.met.geometry.Level]], Option[String], Option[scala.collection.Map[String,models.Observation]]))
[error]     (JsPath \ "referenceTime").writeNullable[String] and
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Not really, no. Dropped doing this for the moment, and simply used a simple Seq to handle it. May try to go back and take a look at the problem again later.

Comment: I've looked at this again; still get the same problem. Added additional details - may be an obvious issue, but I'm just not seeing why it works for the simple case but not the more complex one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was a copy error, but the first class is missing the name of the second field:

```
#                                 ↓↓↓
case class ObjSeries(id: String,   Map[String, MyObj] )
```

Apart from that, what you have should work. Are you sure is this code that is failing?